# Converting integrals to polar coordinates

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates, multiple-integral

Suppose we want to find the area between the circles $x^2+y^2=1$ and $x^2+y^2=2$ using integrals in polar coordinates.

> I understand that the integral is $$\int_{1} ^{2} \int_{0} ^{2\pi}r dθdr$$ as the radius $r$ extends from $1$ to $2$ and goes one full circle. But,

If I wanted to write this integral in the form $$I=\int_{} ^{} \int_{U} ^{}f(x,y) d(x,y)$$

and then convert it to polar coordinates $$I=\int_{1} ^{2} \int_{0} ^{2\pi}f(rcosθ,rsinθ) rdθdr$$
**how can I find $f(x,y)$** in order to do this?

Comment: In Cartesian coordinates, the element of area is simply $dx\,dy$ and $f(x,y)\equiv 1$.

Comment: Why do you hide part of your question ??

Comment: @YvesDaoust So that the point of my question gets across easier

Comment: @YvesDaoust How did we get that $f(x,y)=1$ ?

Comment: The integrand is $dx\,dy$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that this double integral is for area, so the only thing that will occupy the integrand is your Jacobian. When converting from polar back to rectangular, the integrand $r$ becomes $1$.

EDIT: If you are confused about why this is, set up a Jacobian matrix with the conversions. Let's pretend we are in rectangular and going to polar to make my job easier.

We know $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$. Now, when we convert to polar, we have to miltiply the integrand by the following determinant matrix called the Jacobian matrix since we have changed our variables.

$$J=\begin{vmatrix}x_r & x_v \\ y_r & y_v\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}\cos\theta & \sin\theta \\ -r\sin\theta & r\cos\theta\end{vmatrix}=r\cos^2\theta+r\sin^2\theta=r$$

Thus, upon converting from polar back to rectangular, we must divide by this factor $r$. This is why $f(x,y)=1$

We then change the differentials back to $dx$ and $dy$.

Additionally, we rearrange the equations and change the bounds accordingly.

Comment: This is not very useful at the moment

Comment: It just means that to find areas $f=1$

Comment: I am editing to show why the first part is true, give me a minute :)

Comment: @Michael See if this helps now.

Comment: The Jacobian matrix confuses me even more as I have no idea what it is.

Comment: Okay, when we change coordinates with double and triple integrals, this affects our differentials as well. In rectangular coordinates, we are summing a lot of small rectangles. In polar, this shape becomes like a wedge of a circle. To account for this change of shape, we must multiply by some value which happens to be equal to the determinant of a Jacobian matrix. Understanding exactly how this works is not important, just know that you must do it for now.

Comment: @LanierFreeman Okay, I understand this. But my question is what is $f(x,y)$ here?

Comment: Note for your polar equation, $f(r, \theta)=r$. As I showed above, we know that when we convert our integrand $I$ from rectangular to polar, the integrand becomes $I\cdot r$. Thus, if we are to convert back to rectangular from polar, we have $I/r$. Since the integrand is $r$, we have $r/r=1$. Thus, $f(x,y)=1$.

Comment: I should add that for any double integral involving area, if the differentials are rectangular the integrand will ALWAYS be $1$.

Comment: @LanierFreeman Thank you! But why does $1$ always occur?

Comment: I may be mistaken, but believe this is right. 

Because the bounds of integration correspond with the region, it should evaluate to the area of the region. The integrand $1$ functions as a sort of identity here giving us the value of $1$ area.